# visual studio navigation canceled

Tags: visual-studio-2005

When trying to view DataAdapters or some forms in Visual Studio 2005, sometimes I get an error that says "Navigation to the webpage was canceled". Sometimes this error will go just when restarting VS, other times I can't get it to disappear at all!

Any ideas?

Comment: Q: ASP.Net?  To a local web server (e.g. MSVS)?  Or are you just trying to access "help"?  ALSO: Check your IE settings: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967941.  Or switch to Chrome or Firefox as your default browser :)

Comment: No it's a Winforms application, no web connections at all!

Comment: Not trying to access help, and not using IE or any other browser! This is all when trying to edit a DataAdapter in visual studio 2005.

Comment: Please take a look at these links, and see if any of them help: [MSVS Express won't open a console project](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/40fde5ae-a179-42af-91f6-e2c488b5375f), [Security, unblock .chm file](http://anotherlab.rajapet.net/2010/08/resolving-to-webpage-was-canceled-with.html)

Comment: I've just tried logging into my PC as the Administrator user and it works fine, which will point to there being an issue with my profile. Thanks for the link! If I find out what it is with my profile, then I will post the solution.